# File uploading but name is empty

Tags: php, json, swift, file-upload

I have an IOS app that uses PHP for my API. My file upload is working fine but the name of the file is not appending to the file. I've mirrored other pages in my app but it's still not working although others are working fine.  I’m able to see the file on the server, but the name is notes-.jpg. It’s not appending the puuid to the name per the code.  I've implemented MessageKit on the ViewController that isn't working (just in case it makes a difference). Here is my code below, I feel like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack. The code is a little sloppy (please don't judge).

```
func createBodyWithParams(_ parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }


    // if file is not selected, it will not upload a file to server, because we did not declare a name file
    var filename = ""

    if imageSelected == true {
        filename = "notes-\(puuid).jpg"
        print("name of file", filename)
    }


    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body as Data

}

 func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
  print("im in upload")
  let avame = user!["ava"]
  let user_id = user!["id"] as! String
  let me = user!["username"] as! String
  let recipientfe = getmessages["recipient"]
  let uuidfe = getmessages["uuid"] as! String
  let recipient = getmessages["username"] as! String
  let rid = String(describing: getmessages["sender_id"]!)
let puuid = UUID().uuidString
    let text = ""

  let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/messagepost.php")!    
  var request = URLRequest(url: url)      
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let parameters = ["sender_id": user_id, "uuid": uuidfe, "sender": me, "recipient_id": rid, "recipient": recipient, "puuid": puuid, "text": text]

  let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
  request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  var data = Data()

  if image != nil {
    data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
  }
  request.httpBody = createBodyWithParams(parameters, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: data, boundary: boundary)

  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          if error != nil {
              Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
            print("Server Error")
              return
          }

          do {

              guard let data = data else {
                  Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                print("Data Error")
                  return
              }

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

              guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                  return
              }
              if parsedJSON["status"] as! String == "200" {
                let newurl = parsedJSON["path"]
                self.isSendingPhoto = true
                  guard let url = newurl else {
                    return
                  }
                var message = Message(messageuser: self.sender, image: image)
                message.downloadURL = url as? URL

                    self.save(message)
                    self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom()

              } else {

                  if parsedJSON["message"] != nil {
                      let message = parsedJSON["message"] as! String
                      Helper().showAlert(title: "Error", message: message, in: self)
                    print("where am i", parsedJSON["message"] as Any)
                  }

              }

          } catch {
              Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
            print("where am i 2")
          }

      })
  }.resume()        

}
```

PHP Upload File

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST["uuid"])) {
    $id = htmlentities($_REQUEST["id"]);
    $recipient = htmlentities($_REQUEST["recipient"]);
    $recipient_id = htmlentities($_REQUEST["recipient_id"]);
    $uuid = htmlentities($_REQUEST["uuid"]);
    $puuid = htmlentities($_REQUEST["puuid"]);
    $text = htmlentities($_REQUEST["text"]);
    $sender = htmlentities($_REQUEST["sender"]);
    $sender_id = htmlentities($_REQUEST["sender_id"]);

if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 1) {

    $folder = "/home/xxxxx/public_html/notes/" . $uuid;

    // if no posts folder, create it
    if (!file_exists($folder)) {
        mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
    }

    $picture = $folder . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            chmod($picture,0777);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $picture)) {

        $path = "http://localhost/notes/" . $uuid . "/notes-" . $puuid . ".jpg"; 

        $returnArray["message"] = "Post has been made with picture";

        $returnArray["path"] = $path;
        $returnArray["status"] = "200";
    } else {
        $returnArray["message"] = "Post has been made without picture";
        $path = "";
    }
        $result=$access->insertMessage($recipient, $recipient_id, $uuid, $sender,$sender_id, $text, $path);
       // STEP 2.5 If posts are found, append them to $returnArray
       if (!empty($result)) {

        $returnArray["message"] = $result;
       $result = $access->updatebadge($recipient_id);
}
    else {
    $returnArray["message"] = "Couldnt insert". $puuid ."";

    }



 // if data is not passed - show posts except id of the user

}
else {

    $username = htmlentities($_REQUEST["username"]);
    $uuid = htmlentities($_REQUEST["uuid"]);
    $recipient_id = htmlentities($_REQUEST["recipient_id"]);

    $message = $access->conversation($username, $uuid, $recipient_id);

    if (!empty($message)) {
        $returnArray["message"] = $message;
    }

}

}
$access->disconnect();
echo json_encode($returnArray);



?>
```

Comment: Were you able to locate the uploaded file in the server ?

Comment: you get the file name in the print() ?

Comment: @sayooj I’m able to locate the file on the server based on the timestamp. But the name of it is notes-.jpg it’s not appending the puuid based on the code

Comment: @angel inside of the createparams function I get the filename but not within uploadimage

Comment: There's an alarmingly high number of `htmlentities()` calls here. As none of these pertain to HTML display escaping you shouldn't be calling this function at all.

Comment: @tadman do you think that’s impacting the puuid from attaching to the file name or is that just general feedback?

Comment: It's generally a super bad idea to escape things for HTML before inserting in the database. This is how you get messes like `&amp;` showing up in your final documents. It also means you need to de-escape for HTML, re-escape for JSON if that's your display context.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The body and headers in Swift were incorrect and weren't sending the correct file name.

I changed the body to:

```
// web development and MIME Type of passing information to the web server
  let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
  request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  // access / convert image to Data for sending to the server
  var data = Data()

  // if picture has been selected, compress the picture before sending to the server
  if image != nil {
    data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
  }

  // building the full body along with the string, text, file parameters
  request.httpBody = Helper().body(with: parameters, filename: "notes-\(puuid).jpg", filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: data, boundary: boundary) as Data
```